# Spring doesn't close hibernate session after transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to catch a ConstraintViolationException in my service layer and rethrowing a user defined checked exception.  I'm catching the exception in my controller and adding an error object to my BindingResult. I'm using declarative transaction management I've tried to make my DAO a Repository and added a PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor to catch a spring translated exception.  I've also added a txAdvice to rollback on all throwables.  My exception does get caught but I'm getting an error 500 with:

```
Hibernate: insert into user (email, password, first_name, last_name, userType) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 1)
[acme]: [WARN ] - 2013-Feb-05 11:12:43 -  SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions(): SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
[acme]: [ERROR] - 2013-Feb-05 11:12:43 -  SqlExceptionHelper:logExceptions(): Duplicate entry 'admin' for key 'email_unique'
[acme]: [DEBUG] - 2013-Feb-05 11:12:43 -  HibernateTransactionManager:processCommit(): Initiating transaction commit
[acme]: [DEBUG] - 2013-Feb-05 11:12:43 -  HibernateTransactionManager:doCommit(): Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
[acme]: [ERROR] - 2013-Feb-05 11:12:43 -  AssertionFailure:<init>(): HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.test.model.AdminUser entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
[acme]: [DEBUG] - 2013-Feb-05 11:12:43 -  HibernateTransactionManager:doRollbackOnCommitException(): Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.test.model.AdminUser entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:225)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:468)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping (method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    @Transactional
    public String registerAdmin(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") AdminUser user, BindingResult bindingResult, ModelMap model)  {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "admin/admins/form";
        } 
        else if (!user.getPassword().equals(user.getConfirmPassword())) {
            bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("user.confirmPassword", "Passwords don't match"));
            return "admin/admins/form";
        }
        else {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(), null));
            try {
                userService.save(user);
                return "redirect:/admin/admins";
            } catch(ApplicationException ce) {
                bindingResult.addError(new ObjectError("user.email", "Email already registered"));
                return "admin/admins/form";
            }

        }

    }
```

Part of my Spring config:

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.dao, com.test.service" />
     <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties"/>  

    <import resource="springapp-security.xml"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    <property name="username" value="test"/>
    <property name="password" value="test"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="classpath*:com/test/model/hbm/**/*.hbm.xml" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <value>
        hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        hibernate.show_sql=true
      </value>
    </property>
  </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven />
  <bean id="transactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
  <tx:advice id="txAdvice">
  <tx:attributes>
  <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
  </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Service layer:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

    private UserDAO dao;


    @Override
    public void save(User c) throws ApplicationException {
        try {
            dao.save(c);
        } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException cve) {
            throw new ApplicationException("email already registered");
        }
    }
```

If I don't catch the runtime exception I don't get the hibernate exception (don't flush the session..)

Comment: From your code it looks like the transaction is starting at the controller and catching an exception.  In this case no rollback would occur(Not sure if that is what you want to do).  From your post you say that the service layer is starting a transaction and catching an exception.  Could you post that code as well.

Comment: My service layer is not starting the transaction, it starts in the controller sorry If I'm not being clear. I've posted my service code.  Also from my stacktrace I see that it is being rolled back..HibernateTransactionManager:doRollbackOnCommitException(): Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to remove the transaction annotation from your controller and add it to the service layer.

The service layer would look like below.  If your service layer is throwing a checked exception you can add that to your annotation so that the insert is not even attempted to be committed.

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

private UserDAO dao;


@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor=ApplicationException.class)
public void save(User c) throws ApplicationException {
    try {
        dao.save(c);
    } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException cve) {
        throw new ApplicationException("email already registered");
    }
}
```

What is happening currently in your code is that the transaction is not being rolled back but has to rollback because it actually tried to commit the data but because a database constraint the transaction had to be rolled back.  By forcing the rollback with the @Transactional(rollbackFor=ApplicationException.class) it will not allow the transaction to perform a commit but it will rollback and your app will still add the error to the BindingResult.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell why I can't have the transaction start and end around the controller method? Also I have tried your solution without specifying the exception in the annotation because I have the txAdvice in my configuration to rollback on all throwables and that didn't work

Comment: In your controller method there is no exception being thrown.  There would be no way for you to tell the transaction manager to rollback the exception.  The only way this could be done is by starting the transaction programatically in your controller or throwing an exception from your controller.  These are some reasons why you would not want transactions in your controller.  You do most likely do not want to be forced to throw an exception from the controller or deal with transaction management in your controller code.

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginning to understand how Spring uses AOP to rollback transactions when exceptions happen..Thank you!!!